# Open, focus and bring to the front apps in the dock using ⌘-number

Tags: keyboard, applescript, karabiner

How would one open, focus and bring to the front apps in the dock using ⌘-`number`, where `number` corresponds to their position in the dock. Basically, all the behaviour of clicking the app in the dock, but with ⌘-`number`. So ⌘-1 should behave the same as clicking the app besides finder, etc. Off-by-one in either direction is not a problem.

If determining the position of an app in the dock is difficult, assume they don't move and I can hardcode a ⌘-`number` for each of them.

Perhaps this could be achieved with some apple script mapped to a shortcut, or with karabiner-elements?

I work with both mac and linux, and linux has an equivalent shortcut that I use a lot. It would be great to have it here too, given how useful it is.

Comment: Why not put each app on a different Space, then you can use the built-in key commands to switch between them? See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme and
https://superuser.com/questions/1187532/macos-sierra-full-screen-multi-desktop-with-menu-bar for some ideas.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's a neat idea, but I'm already scripting window ordering and focus a bit to achieve some behaviour I value. In particular I like to be able to keep focus on the current window but put it behind the next one up (sort of like ctrl-option clicking a title bar). So I'd like to keep them all maximised and focusable at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the question is a duplicate of [OSX Dock's Equivalent of Ubuntu Launcher's Super + (1, 2, 3)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130963/osx-docks-equivalent-of-ubuntu-launchers-super-1-2-3?rq=1)

they are the same, because super=⌘.

I have flagged as duplicate.